# Adding rates concurrently for each date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the below data,
'''

```
CREATE TABLE dates(Dates DATE, Rate NUMBER);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES('18-JUN-2019',200);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES('19-JUN-2019',200);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES('20-JUN-2019',300);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES('21-JUN-2019',300);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES('22-JUN-2019',300);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES('23-JUN-2019',400);
```

'''

This is the answer I need to get,

```
   Date              Rate
18-JUN-2019           200 
19-JUN-2019           400
20-JUN-2019           700
21-JUN-2019           1000
22-JUN-2019           1300
23-JUN-2019           1700
```

I am using Oracle SQL, what would be the easiest SQL statement I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum:

```
select d.date, d.number, sum(d.number) over (order by d.date) as running_sum
from dates d;
```

Comment: Thank a lot, this was helpful